# Как собрать проект одним exe файлом?

Tags: c++

Получается вот так. Как можно собрать всю в один exe файл?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я не уверен но он уже собран (`example.exe`), а остальное это логи, дебагер и другое . попробуйте скопировать `exe` в другое место и запустить, должно заработать

Answer (score 2):

взять из этой кучи .exe и поместить куда душе угодно. Он уже готов и самодостаточен

Comment: Он может быть совершенно не самодостаточен, если собран с использованием рантайма в виде DLL.